# I can't seem to figure out how to generate multiple random numbers to equal a score of 10

Tags: python

What I have to do is compare PlayerOne's random generated number with PlayerTwo's. The numbers are between 1 and 13. Everytime someone wins they get 1 point. The first Player to 10 is the winner. I got as far as generating the first random numbers for each player and creating a score chart that adds 1 to the winner. I don't understand how I get it to generate two more times with the click of the return button instead of automatically. Also, I don't understand how to make the score chart I made automatically understand which player won and add a point to the winning player. Thanks.

```
import random


for PlayerOne in range(1):
    Score = 1
    PlayerOne = random.randint(1, 13)
    print(("Player One: %s" % PlayerOne))

    for PlayerTwo in range(1):
        PlayerTwo = random.randint(1, 13)
        print(("Player Two: %s" % PlayerTwo))


    if PlayerOne > PlayerTwo:
        print("Player One wins!")
        print(("Player One: %s" % Score))
        print("Player Two: 0")

    else:
        print("Player Two wins!")
        print("\nScore:")
        print("Player One: 0")
        print(("Player Two: %s" % Score))
```

Comment: Why are you doing `for PlayerTwo in range(1)` then reassigning `PlayerTwo`? I don't think you understand how `for` loops work...

Comment: Have you done some basic learning about how the language works?  That would be far more helpful to you than just getting one question answered.

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND Can you explain the correct way if you have time?

Comment: No, this is not something where "the correct way" can simply be "explained". You are writing things that don't make any sense. You must study the language first.

Answer (score 3):

consider your code snippet:

```
for PlayerTwo in range(1):
  PlayerTwo = randint()
  print PlayerTwo
```

`range(1)` is equivalent to `[0]`, e.g. a list with one element whose value is zero.  Thus, your for loop executes exactly once, assigning the value 0 to the variable PlayerTwo.  Subsequently you overwrite this variable with some other integer.

The reason that others are suggesting you look at how for loops work, is that the code in your for loop is only executed one time, which is presumably not what you want to do.  It may not be for loops that are confusing you, it may be `range`.

Because you don't know the exact number of games that take place, a for loop is probably not ideal anyway.

Here is pseudocode (not real code) for how I would approach this problem.  Try to understand why I use `while` and not `for`:

```
while p1score < 10 and p2score < 10:
  p1 = randint()
  p2 = randint()
  if p1 > p2:
    p1score++
  elif p2 > p1:
    p2score++
```

Comment: would would you make p1score and p2score equal to?

Comment: to start out, set them to 0

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out thanks too aestrivex! If anyone see's anything wrong or something I that doesn't look right let me know.

```
import random

input ('Please press "Enter" to begin the automated War card game.')

PlayerOneScore = 0
PlayerTwoScore = 0

while PlayerOneScore < 10 and PlayerTwoScore < 10:
    PlayerOne = random.randint(1, 13)
    PlayerTwo = random.randint(1, 13)
    if PlayerOne > PlayerTwo:
        PlayerOneScore += 1


    elif PlayerTwo > PlayerOne:
        PlayerTwoScore += 1



    print("Player One: ",PlayerOne)
    print("Player Two: ",PlayerTwo)
    print("\nScoreboard:")
    print("Player One Score: ",PlayerOneScore)
    print("Player Two Score: ",PlayerTwoScore,"\n\n\n")

    if PlayerOne > PlayerTwo:
        print("Player One Wins!")

    else:
        print("Player Two Wins!")
```

Comment: a) You should test your code!

b) input() does not do quite what you think it does.  input expects the user to insert properly formatted python code onto one line and immediately evaluates it (specifically, it calls the `eval` builtin).  Merely pressing enter will cause the call to input() to be nothing, which causes a parse error in `eval`.  If you really want the interaction of the user pressing enter, you can use `raw_input` here which returns a string and won't cause this problem.